# asp.net webforms - Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I am trying to show a pop up dialog with a message for the user but this pop up appears in some asp.net webforms and shows an error in other web forms although the js code is the same

how can i debug and solve this?

jquery-3.4.1.js
Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'
[Scope] jQuery.readyException

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" lang="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" lang="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/custom.js" lang="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Content/jquery-ui-legacy.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script type="text/javascript" >
    function ShowPopup(message) {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").html(message);
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "نافذة الحفظ",
                buttons: {
                    "إغلاق": function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });
        });
    };
</script>
```

**Edited**
adding validators in the form causes the issue. how it can be solved without removing validators?

```
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="invalidCount" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="err-text" 
    ControlToValidate="textboxCount" 
    Type="integer" 
    ErrorMessage="يرجى إدخال عدد صحيح!" 
    Operator="DataTypeCheck"                                    
    Display="Dynamic">
</asp:CompareValidator>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="requiredSeizuredItemCount" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="err-text" 
    Display="Dynamic" 
    ErrorMessage="يرجى ملئ هذا الحقل!" 
    OnServerValidate="requiredSeizuredItemCount_ServerValidate">
</asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" 
  ID="textboxConsequentDamageMaxLength"
  ControlToValidate="textboxConsequentDamage"
  ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,300}$"
  ErrorMessage="الرجاء إدخال 300 حرف كحد أقصى"
  CssClass="err-text"
  Display="Dynamic">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Make sure the jquery-ui is included in *all* your pages.  Sounds like it's not included in some

Comment: @freedomn-m all scripts are included same as this code is there an issue with it?

Comment: Maybe add a ValidationGroup to the validators?